# C++, why does std::set allow lower_bound() on a type different than that of the set elements, but only if I add less<> in the set declaration?

Tags: c++, set, less, comparator

I have this class with an overloaded comparator:

```
struct Foo {
    int x;
    bool operator < (Foo other) const {
        return x < other.x;
    }
    bool operator < (int val) const {
        return x < val;
    }
};
```

and I make a set on it:

```
set<Foo> s;
```

I'm allowed to call lower_bound() on a Foo, but not on an int (as you would expect).

```
s.lower_bound(Foo{3}); // works
s.lower_bound(3); //"no matching member function for call to 'lower_bound'
```

But if instead I declare s with a less<> :

```
set<Foo,less<>>
```

Both calls work:

```
s.lower_bound({3});
s.lower_bound(3);
```

Why?

Comment: Because [`less<>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less_void) deduces left and right side separately. The default `less<Foo>` only allows Foos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why does std::set allow lower_bound() on a type different than that of the set elements

Because it is useful, and potentially more efficient.

Consider for example a set of `std::string`s. Creating (large) strings is expensive. If you have a string view, you can use `std::less<>` to compare the view to the strings of the set without having to construct a string from that view.

> but only if I add less<> in the set declaration?

Because the second type parameter, to which you passed `std::less<>` as the argument is the functor that the set uses to compare the elements. `std::less<>` is what is able to compare objects of different types. The default comparator is `std::less<T>` which can only compare objects of type `T`. `std::less<>` isn't the default because it didn't exist when `std::set` was standardised.

Comment: You should add that it is not necessary to be able to compare objects of different types, but the comparator needs to define is_transparent member, which less<> does but less<T> does not.

Comment: @gerum the comparator needs to be able to compare the types that the `lower_bound` is called with, *as well as* defining `is_transparent`

Comment: @Caleth You are right, i forgot any "only" in my comment. -> "... it is not only necessary ..."